# Opening visual studio 2008 in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed both visual studio 2008 and 2010. When I try to open a visual studio 2008 solution file it opens in visual studio 2010. It does not open in vs 2008.

Comment: Start VC2008 first and open the solution using File menu.

Comment: yes, like that only i am opening.but i need to open through .sln(solution) file

Comment: When you open your solution in a higher version of visual studio than what it was originally created in, it will be migrated to that higher version, so that' obvious that you can't open it in previous version

Comment: All the code is in the lower version only it is not migrated

Comment: i want to open the visual studio 2008 project just by double click the solution file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the .sln file in file explorer, right click, select "Open With", select "Visual Studio 2008" or "Visual Studio version Selector".

If it doesn't work, Select the .sln file in file explorer, right click, select "Open With", Select "Choose Default Program" and there you can select Microsoft Visual Studio 2008". It might be hidden if you are OS like vista or Windows 7. There is one line with an arrow to expand all available programs

Hope that helps

Milind

Comment: where i can find Choose Default Program?

Comment: @user1627761: Updated the solution. Please check. If it helps mark it as solution/upvote.

Comment: yes that is correct.I expand the one line arrow also but there i am not able to find visual studio 2008

Comment: @user1627761: If Visual Studio is installed on your machine. It has to be there. If you have uninstalled while installing VS2010, then naturally it will not be there.

Comment: i am sure i am having visual studio.i can open Visual studio 2008 .

Comment: @user1627761: Yes, you have VS. But do you have both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 on your machine ? Check in all programs.

Comment: yes i am having both. but it only showing VS 2010 only but i want to open in 2008

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the project from the file->open menu?

Comment: yes that is opening for me.  i want to open the visual studio 2008 project just by double click the solution file.